# Intuitive explanation of why in binomial distribution the peak is reached at $x = np$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, intuition, binomial-distribution

Suppose we toss $20$ coins with probability $p$. When we plot the graph, we see that the peak is reached at the p-th point in the graph, that is, around $x = 20p$ in this case. Can I get an intuitive (not with the binomial distribution formula) explanation why that is the case? Why is probability more at the point and decreases along a (smooth) curve on either sides. What exactly has the experiment number (which is $x$) got to do with this?

Comment: In the case $n \to \infty$ you can appeal to some general concepts such as the frequentist definition of probability to see that the number of successes will be close to $np$ with high probability.

Comment: (Cont.)  But for smaller $n$ there is a nontrivial competition going on that is kind of hard to explain without details: on the one hand there is the probability of any one sequence with $k$ successes, which is $p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$, and that's biggest when either $k=0$ if $p<1/2$ or $k=n$ when $p>1/2$ (when $p=1/2$ it's always the same). But this has to compete with the larger number of sequences with more of a balance between successes and failures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "peak" of the binomial distribution is also called the "expected value" or the binomial distribution.

Say you have a binomial experiment that will involve $n$ trials and each trial has a $p$ rate of success. Then what is the "expected number" of success's? It makes sense that the expected number of success's is proportional to both $n$ and $p$.

If we conduct more trials (increase $n$) then we should expect more success's. If we increase the success rate (increase $p$) then we should expect more success's. Thus the fact that the expected number of success's (the peak of the probability distribution) should equal $np$ makes sense intuitively.

The details on proving that this is the peak of the curve is $np$ comes from the the definition of the binomial distribution and expected value.

However, you incorrectly stated that the probability decreases on either side of the peak along a smooth curve. This is not true, since the binomial distribution is a discrete distribution, it's probability distribution will be "blocky" and not "smooth". That being said, for large $n$ the binomial distribution can be approximated by a normal curve, which is smooth.

Comment: That's a pretty nitpicky way of viewing "on either side".

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: The comparison "on either side" of the mode is about comparing $P(X=[np])$ with $P(X=[np]+1)$ and $P(X=[np]-1)$, where $[\cdot]$ is the round to nearest integer function. The fact that a histogram is blocky has nothing really to do with that. (That said, the case when $p=1/2$ and $n$ is odd has some commentary along these lines to be made.)

Comment: I was addressing the comment the OP wrote that the distribution "decreases along a smooth line on either side."